# Variables in After Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I currently have the following:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :asker, :class => "User", :foreign_key => "asker_id"
  has_one :track, :as => :trackable

  after_create :make_track

  def make_track
    create_track
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions
  has_one :track, :as => :trackable

  after_create :make_track

  def make_track
    create_track
  end
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :trackable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

What I want to do is get the tracks(Track) that belongs_to a user(User) in order to get:

```
u = User.first
t = u.tracks
```

I tried putting in:

```
  def make_track
    create_track(:user_id => :user)
  end

  def make_track
    create_track(:user_id => :user_id)
  end
```

but it doesn't help. How do I insert the user_id of the User that saved the current question/product in the after create?

After following mu is too short's answer below. I got the output which is this:

```
  SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
  Question Create (0.2ms)   INSERT INTO `questions` (`votes`, `created_at`, `asker_id`, `product_id`, `updated_at`, `question`) VALUES(0, '2011-05-23 07:55:25', 1, 1, '2011-05-23 07:55:25', 'the eight')
  Track Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM `tracks` WHERE (`tracks`.trackable_id = 13 AND `tracks`.trackable_type = 'Question') LIMIT 1
  Track Columns (1.3ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `tracks`
  Track Create (0.3ms)   INSERT INTO `tracks` (`trackable_id`, `created_at`, `trackable_type`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES(13, '2011-05-23 07:55:25', 'Question', '2011-05-23 07:55:25', NULL)
  SQL (54.6ms)   COMMIT
```

I tried outputting `self.user` in `after_create` which resulted in `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just call the appropriate accessor method on `self`:

```
def make_track
  create_track(:user_id => self.user)
end
```

Comment: the user_id in Track contains nothing after this change.

Comment: Maybe because model it belongs to also does not have user_id attribute set?

Comment: There were conflicts in my model about the user_id and asker_id.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL you posted suggests that the problem is that the user is not being set on the question (which is why it is nil when passing to create_track).

Should Question really belong directly to User, or does it belong to User through Product?

Comment: Yes. I agree with this and it has been causing the problem.